# Multiple SQL Query

Tags: mysql, multiple-select

I have two tables that I want to query.

**members_table**

```
 --date_joined--user_id--email--user_name
```

**messages_table**

```
 --date_sent--message_id--message--user_name
```

I would like to create a query that will count the number of new member signups for each day (between to dates) and also the emails sent between the same two date.

I want to use this data to create a table that shows the count of these two tables for each day (between 2 dates)

My question is on the sql query, how to right it. I have tried various this but its not working

This is what I have tried so far but its not giving the correct results

```
 SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS memebrs,
        date_joined AS date,
        (SELECT 
          COUNT(message_id)
          FROM messaages_table)
         )AS messages
  FROM members_table
  WHERE date_joined >= '2013-01-01'
  AND date_joined <= '2013-01-31'
  GROUP BY date
```

Comment: post what you have tried ?

Comment: I have just updated, showing what I have tried thus far

Comment: messages are related with user_name ?

Comment: hello, what if the tables are not related by user_name

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
   SELECT COUNT(a.user_id) AS memebrs, a.date_joined AS JoinDate , COUNT(b.message_id)
   FROM members_table a 
   JOIN messaages_table b ON a.user_name = b.user_name 
   WHERE a.date_joined BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31'
   GROUP BY a.date_joined;
```

Comment: i need the two tables...what i gave above is just a part of the table, they have more columns, which prevent them from being one table

Comment: Please elaborate your question, what you exactly need is not clear. Explain with some sample data.

Comment: I basically have people signing up and I store this in a table...the same people then send various messages to each other etc...i store that in another table...i want to be able to produce a report that will show me in a single html table, the daily activity on the site...[new signups, new message, etc etc] for each given day in the search query...i.e. count rows in various tables and returning this as a single array with grouped by date

Comment: Hello, what if the two tables did not have any relationship (i.e no user_name)